# Is $|e^z| \le e$ in disc $e^{it}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have very quite question : is it true that $|e^z| \le e$ in disc $e^{it}$  ? I need it to find roots of other equations...

Comment: Why all the "unclear what you're asking" votes?  This is perfectly clear (except the second sentence).

Comment: What makes the question "very quite"? What "other" equations? There are no equations here to begin with...

Answer (score 6):

Note:

$$\lvert e^z\rvert = e^{\operatorname{Re} z}.$$

Since $\operatorname{Re} z \leqslant 1$ in the unit disk ...

Answer (score 1):

If $z = e^{it}$, then
$$
e^z
= e^{e^{it}}
= e^{\cos t + i \sin t}
= e^{\cos t} \left( \cos \sin t + i \sin \sin t \right)
$$
So
$$
\left| e^{z} \right|
= e^{\cos t}
\in \left[e^{-1}, e^1\right]
= \left[\tfrac1e, e\right].
$$